# AutoMapper: Map Interface to Abstract class - is this possible?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, automapper

I'm using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to map objects between different layers of my application.
On the one side I have an interface which looks like this:

```
public interface MyRepo 
{
    IEnumerable<IRootObject> GetItems(param);
}
```

IRootObject looks like this:

```
public interface IRootObject
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

public interface IFirstSubObject : IRootObject 
{
    string MyFirstProp { get; set; }
}

public interface ISecondSubObject : IRootObject 
{
    string MySecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

So the `GetItems()`call actually returns an array of only `IxxxSubObjectItems`.
On the other side the structure looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyCustomRoot
{
    protected MyCustomRoot(){}
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomFirstSub : MyCustomRoot
{
    public MyCustomFirstSub() : base() {} 
    public string MyFirstProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomSecondSub : MyCustomRoot
{
    public MyCustomSecondSub () : base() {} 
    public string MySecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I've set up the mapper like so

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IRootObject, MyCustomRoot>
    .Include<IFirstSubObject, MyCustomFirstSub>
    .Include<ISecondSubObject, MyCustomSecondSub>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IFirstSubObject, MyCustomFirstSub>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ISecondSubObject, MyCustomSecondSub>();
```

But I keep getting MapperExceptions ("Cannot construct abstract class", which makes sense in a way). I also call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`, and that passes for this code.
If I don't make the `MyCustomRoot` class abstract, then the mapping works, but I get a list of `MyCustomRoot` objects, while I actually would like to have a list of `MyCustomxxxSub`, because there is a Factory later on which uses this type to generate the correct UI...

I hope someone can point me in the right direction for this one!
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found a way to actually do this!
So with the Interfaces and Classes provided above, you can do something like this
(Remember: the `MyCustomRoot` class is abstract)

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IRootObject, MyCustomRoot>
    .Include<IFirstSubObject, MyCustomFirstSub>
    .Include<ISecondSubObject, MyCustomSecondSub>();
```

and then use the followig Map call to map the objects:

```
public List<MyCustomRoot> PerformMapping(List<IRootObject> rootObjects)
{
    var returnList = new List<CustomRoot>();
    foreach(var rootObject in rootObjects)
    {
        var abstractObject = (MyCustomRoot)Mapper.Map(rootObject, rootObject.GetType(), typeof(MyCustomRoot));
        returnList.Add(abstractObject);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Now I actually get an array of `MyCustomRoot` objects, which are all the specific implementations.

This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: could you be more specific about how that differs from the code in your question ? I tried this but still have the "abstract classes cannot be created" exception...

Comment: Okay, it seems versions 4.x don't work but 3.2 does. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

If so, then you want to map to that factory, inject it and let it create the correct instance in due time, since it's the factory that apparently knows what to instantiate.

Comment: Well, not really. The Factory is in another layer, and it gets as input the abstract `MyCustomRoot` object. Thanks for the help anyway!