# Abstract classes with automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class User
{
    /* properties */
}

public class Teacher : User
{

}

public class Student : User
{

}
```

Then I want to map my view model to one of these child class base on a property:

```
public enum UserType
{
    Teacher,
    Student
}

public class UserVM
{
    /* Properties of User */
    public UserType UserType {get; set;}
}
```

Based on UserVM.UserType, I'd like to map to the related child class:

```
userModel.UserType = UserType.Teacher;
//user will be of type Teacher
var user = Mapper.Map<UserVM, User>(userModel);
```

How do I setup my `CreateMap` configurations for this?

Comment: Is the problem that you're trying to map to an abstract class? If you know that the type will be Teacher, why can't you just do Mapper.Map<UserVM, Teacher>() ?

Comment: @someweather, I wanted to take that logic into the mapper because I might have to write that code multiple times to check the type then choose the mapping type.

Comment: Would this be of any help? You would still need some way of accessing the type of the desired inherited class... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578253/automapper-map-interface-to-abstract-class-is-this-possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `ConstructUsing` where you would put the instantiation logic based on the value of the enum:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<UserVM, User>()
    .ConstructUsing(userVM =>
    {
        if (userVM.UserType == UserType.Teacher)
        {
            return new Teacher();
        }
        return new Student();
    });
```